# Novel about a crime in VR. Protagonist starts in medieval fantasy and travels to different servers (bayou, etc) to solve a crime

Tags: story-identification, novel

I believe I read this novel in 2005 or so. It's about a guy that works and plays in VR. I remember that his office is on a virtual beach. It starts in a medieval world where everyone has to talk in medieval dialects. Something happens and this guy sets out to solve the crime. The only two scenes that I can remember are when he talks to a server that is an old guy in the bayou swamp and the end when they are up in a tower with a dragon after having saved the world or something. A lot of the hacking and typical computer stuff is portrayed in the virtual world as real-world analogues.

Any help finding this book would be hugely appreciated. I've been looking for years!

Comment: Hi Welcome to SF&F.  Please take the [tour](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and see if there is anything else that you can add to this post.